# Should this question be answered?

Tags: discussion

[How many people saw Jesus raised from the death?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36985/how-many-people-saw-jesus-raised-from-the-death)

The question shows severe lack of research (literally, the answer is in the same chapter as the one OP cited) and also citing scriptures out of context to make his point about false witnesses. However, my first impression is that the question "How many people saw the resurrected Christ (in the NT)?" is appropriate for this site and could be answered.

In this case, should the question just be answered (and maybe at the same time downvoted), or should it be closed because OP didn't put in the effort that one could expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spite of even my own intuition, "lack of research" is not a valid reason for closing a question on this site. Even the patently stupid questions are not close worthy solely on account of having easy answers that should have been Googled instead.

Often times such poor questions have *other* problems that make them closeable—for example they are often too broad—but the lack of research effort shown is only a reason to down-vote not close.

And if questions shouldn't be closed then they should be answered. Hopefully my own attempt to do so in this case will not come across as too condescending. I did DV the question since one of the main reasons suggested for down voting is lack of research, but I didn't see any obvious reason to close and went ahead and dropped an answer on it. Usually that's the fastest way to get these questions out of the way: answer and move on.